# Python Block Formatting

Tags: python, string, formatting, block, quote

How do I indent a multiline string in the context of string formatting? e.g.

```
'''
<
     %s
>
''' % (paragraph)
```

where paragraph contains newlines. ('foo\nbar')

If I use the above code, I get output like this:

```
'''
<
    foo
bar
>
'''
```

when I really want this:

```
'''
<
    foo
    bar
>
'''
```

I know I could do something like:

```
'''
<
%s
>
''' % (paragraph)
```

but this breaks readability for my purposes.

I also realize I could just write some code to indent all but the first line by 1 indent, but this isn't really an extensible solution (what if I have 2 indents?  or 3? etc.)

**EDIT**:
Before you post an answer, consider how your solution works with something like this:

```
'''
<
    %s
    <
        %s
        %s
        <
            %s
        >
    >
>
''' % (p1, p2, p3, p4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the simple doesn't suit your purposes. Either you need to use a document object model and a flattening system with appropriate indentation.

Or, you could do something fairly hacky to detect the amount of whitespace before each substitution. This is pretty fragile:

```
import re

def ind_sbt(text,indent='\t'):
    return text.replace('\n','\n%s' % (indent,))

def adjust_indents(fmtstr,*args):
    """Hacky, crude detection of identation level"""
    indented_substitutions = re.compile(r'\n(\s+)%s')
    return fmtstr % tuple([ ind_sbt(arg,indent=i) for (arg,i) in zip(args,indented_substitutions.findall(fmtstr))])

p1 = p2 = p3 = p4 = "foo\nbar"

print adjust_indents('''
<
    %s
    <
        %s
        %s
        <
            %s
        >
    >
>
''',p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

Yielding:

```
<
        foo
        bar
        <
                foo
                bar
                foo
                bar
                <
                        foo
                        bar
                >
        >
>
```

Comment: Unfortunate that there's no simple way to do this, but I guess this answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
'''
<
   %s
>
''' % ("\n   ".join(paragraph.split("\n")))
```

Result:

```
<
   foo
   bar
>
```

The string used in the `.join()` method must contain the same whitespace (plus a `\n` at the start) as whatever comes before `%s` in your string.

Comment: Breaks readability for my purposes, as I mentioned in the OP.

Comment: This is similar to what Yuval proposed - it breaks for an arbitrary number of leading indents.

Comment: But you control the leading indents, so you can just copy them into the joining string.

Comment: This is okay, until I'm doing lots of replacement.  It becomes tedious to keep track of indentation level for each paragraph.

Comment: Then I guess you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect the Python interpreter to automagically indent your `paragraph`. Would you want the interpreter messing around with your data? (Hint: NO.)

What you can do is inject whitespace:

```
'''
<
    %s
>
''' % (paragraph.replace('\n','\n    ')) # assuming 4 space soft tabs
```

But I would very much refrain from that unless you absolutely have to, since you have no idea which line endings you might be dealing with, and generally feels kind of awkward.

Comment: This doesn't work for an arbitrary number of tabs.  If I were to have "<\n\t\t%s\n>", this would break.

Comment: True. For arbitrary indentation I would use something more fit for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Python's [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html) module is your friend, especially its `initial_indent` and `subsequent_indent` parameters.

Comment: I was having a look at this. A problem is that textwrap will get rid of existing `\n` and if you use `replace_whitespace=False` it will preserve them, but not indent.